Ansible filters logic to process two dicts and add a new dict property based on key value
I have
- name: Replace group_ids with group_names in var_users
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    var_users:
      - group_ids: ["e40c1163-269f-41f7-5555-57e1788a1999", "2742113c-44a6-59e3-48de-60b72e40ed83"]
        name: "marko"
      - group_ids: ["e40c1163-269f-41f7-5555-57e1788a1999"]
        name: "user"
    var_groups:
      - id: "2742113c-44a6-59e3-48de-60b72e40ed83"
        name: "admins"
      - id: "e40c1163-269f-41f7-5555-57e1788a1999"
        name: "users"

What is the approach to corelate var_groups id with var_users group_ids to have resulting var_users have group nameintstead of group_ids?
The expected results should be
var_users:
  - group_ids: ["users", "admins"]
    name: "marko"
  - group_ids: ["users"]
    name: "user"


What is the expected result?

Ahh, I submitted before final edit. Now the question is updated with expected result.

Convert var_groups to a dictionary
  var_groups_dict: "{{ var_groups |
                       items2dict(key_name='id', value_name='name') }}"

gives
  var_groups_dict:
    2742113c-44a6-59e3-48de-60b72e40ed83: admin
    e40c1163-269f-41f7-5555-57e1788a1999: users

Use it to substitute id by name
  group_ids: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for ids in var_users | map(attribute='group_ids' )%}
    - {group_ids: {{ ids | map('extract', var_groups_dict) }}}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}

gives
  group_ids:
    - group_ids: [users, admin]
    - group_ids: [users]

Then, zip the lists and combine the items
  result: "{{ var_users | zip(group_ids) | map('combine') }}"

gives what you want
  result:
    - group_ids: [users, admin]
      name: marko
    - group_ids: [users]
      name: user



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    var_users:
      - group_ids: [e40c1163-269f-41f7-5555-57e1788a1999, 2742113c-44a6-59e3-48de-60b72e40ed83]
        name: marko
      - group_ids: [e40c1163-269f-41f7-5555-57e1788a1999]
        name: user
    var_groups:
      - id: 2742113c-44a6-59e3-48de-60b72e40ed83
        name: admin
      - id: e40c1163-269f-41f7-5555-57e1788a1999
        name: users

    var_groups_dict: "{{ var_groups |
                     items2dict(key_name='id', value_name='name') }}"
    group_ids: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for ids in var_users | map(attribute='group_ids' )%}
      - {group_ids: {{ ids | map('extract', var_groups_dict) }}}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
    result: "{{ var_users | zip(group_ids) | map('combine') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: var_groups_dict

    - debug:
        var: group_ids | to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: result | to_yaml


Optionally, create the group_names dictionary
  group_names: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for i in var_users %}
    {{ i.name }}: {{ i.group_ids | map('extract', var_groups_dict) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}

In a minimal form, this gives what you need
  group_names:
    marko: [users, admin]
    user: [users]

Then, you can convert it to any list if you want to. For example, the below declaration gives the same result
  result: "{{ group_names |
              dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='group_ids') }}"

Or, you can use the dictionary in a loop. For example,
    - debug:
        msg: "group: {{ item.0.key }} name: {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ group_names | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"

gives (abridged)
  msg: 'group: marko name: users'
  msg: 'group: marko name: admin'
  msg: 'group: user name: users'


Optionally, if you don't want to use Jinja, the below filters give the same result
  result: "{{ var_users |
              zip(var_users | map(attribute='group_ids')
                            | map('map', 'extract', var_groups_dict)
                            | map('community.general.dict_kv', 'group_ids')) |
              map('combine') }}"

, or group_names
  group_names: "{{ dict(var_users | map(attribute='name') |
                        zip(var_users | map(attribute='group_ids')
                                      | map('map', 'extract', var_groups_dict))) }}"



Thank you. I'm curious have you been using GPT or something to generate nicely formated answer? I've tried but without success.

No GPT. Emacs and YAML/Jinja FlyC. See Ansible Other Tools and Programs. (Hope GPT learns from me :)
